# What to do about error "E1696 command-line error: cannot open metadata file "mscorlib.dll" in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

All of a sudden, when trying to run a unit test in Visual Studio 2017, I get errors E1696 command-line error: cannot open metadata file "mscorlib.dll" and also "E2998 PCH warning: an unknown error occurred.  An IntelliSense PCH file was not generated."

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, this seems to be VS2017's way of telling you that you have tried to run a unit test/MS Test on a CPP module that has a Syntax Error in it.  The syntax error is in the module under test, not the test. Typical scenario would be the .CPP module is changed to fix something, a syntax error is accidentally introduced, then any unit testing will generate E1696/E2988 mscorlib/Intellisense errors.  The offending syntax error may not be obvious in the Error List if there are many warnings.  Scrolling down the Error List window may reveal the syntax error, which when fixed, will eliminate the E1696 and E2988 mscorlib.dll + Intellisense errors.

Comment: Ken you are right. I scrolled down and the last line had this. In my case it is a brand new install on a clean system. Thanks

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". RdtUtility C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.targets 46

Answer (score 0):

This answer got me through a similar one. My symptoms were cannot find `mscorlib.tlh` in `./debug`.

The problem was missing `.prob` files in the `vcxproj` file. Deleted those references and the error went away.

Posting this because the answer here actually got me to the problem despite what the compiler was telling me and hours of web searching (hours and hours trying to figure out what was wrong with `mscorlib`).